# Static function returns wrong value?

Tags: java, function, static

I have a small class which contains a static final variable and a static function:

```
public class GlobalConstants {
    public static final boolean ONLINE = true;

    public static boolean isOnline(){
        return ONLINE;
    }
}
```

(of course there is a bit of code duplication, but please ignore that)

I package my program in a runnable jar and get weird result:

```
log.debug(GlobalConstants.isOnline()); //prints false
log.debug(GlobalConstants.ONLINE); //prints true
```

I would expect that they both print "true".

Is the java compiler doing a optimization that causes this strange behavior, or am i missing something?

Comment: You are not setting isOnline, you are setting ONLINE.

Comment: Did you really run this minimal example? Maybe you removed some important parts from the code? I created a project and executed your code. It worked fine.

Comment: @Neuron no, it is part of a big program, but both log.debug lines are called as the program starts and are called after each other. Note that in eclipse it works correctly, only when i package it in a runnable jar the log.debug lines print the wrong values.

Comment: @durbnpoisn isOnline returns the ONLINE variable, so they should both return the same value (ie the value of ONLINE), but the strange thing is they don't.

Comment: IMO the code is correct and should never return false. Perhaps there is a duplicate class somewhere in another package..?

Comment: Write `System.out.print();` in `isOnline()` so that you could see whats happening

Comment: Can you show the actual code? Have you checked the timestamps on the *.class files in the jar? Is any of the codebase doing anything unusual with classloaders, reflection or native methods?

Comment: @AndyThomas i suspect there is indeed something really messed up with my package step, it is quite complicated and indeed does magic with different classloaders, reflection, osgi, although i thought it wasn't related to the program i now try to run. I will jump in my code again to see if i can find something wrong.

Comment: Cheers for the help guys! Found the problem, it appeared that my local maven repository had a lost copy of the library holding the GlobalConstants class. This class was included as dependency in the runnable jar. But that doesn't explain the "false, true" output, unless GlobalConstants.ONLINE is converted to a boolean value by a optimization by the java compiler (because it is a final). It still confuses me a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cheers for the help guys! Found the problem, it appeared that my local maven repository had a lost copy of the library holding the GlobalConstants class. This class was included as dependency in the runnable jar. But that doesn't explain the "false, true" output, unless GlobalConstants.ONLINE is converted to a boolean value by a optimization by the java compiler (because it is a final). It still confuses me a bit.

[update]
I decompiled my class and indeed:

```
System.out.println(GlobalConstants.ONLINE);
System.out.println(GlobalConstants.isOnline());
```

is converted by java compiler in:

```
System.out.println(true);
System.out.println(GlobalConstants.isOnline());
```

Now it is all clear and this explains the result in my original post. Because even when it was using a wrong class version it should have produced the same result (true, true). But because java compiler does magic it is possible that it returned true, false.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this project](http://goo.gl/b7bWy1) I set up with your code. It works just as expected, your error must lie in some parts of the code you removed to simplify your code example.

And always consider that your static code must be executed. If you call the code above from a static context, some circular dependencies may result in some static variables not being initialized before being called

Comment: I indeed agree that it should not return true and false, but true and true, that makes all the sense in the world ;-) Hence my question. I suspect i might do something terrible wrong. I'll post a comment when i find out what.